# Matlab 2021b can not export to stand alone FMU

Tags: matlab, export, simulink

I just upgraded to matlab 2021b. according to the documentation, you can export to an FMU file with
From Simulation tab, click drop-down button for Save. In Export Model To section, click Standalone FMU.

But when I click on Save, in the 'Export Model To' section, I see 'Protected Model', 'Template', and 'Previous Version'. But no 'Standalone FMU'.

What is missing? Do I need to install more parts from matlab?

Answer (score 2):

Exporting to a standalone FMU requires a license for the Simulink Compiler.

Presumably that is what you are missing.

Answer (score -1):

you need to install Simulink Compiler.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).